# Gitlab Runner Error port 443: Operation timed out?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I set up GitLab-runner. I would like to connect to my gitlab.xxx.com. I register runner as docker executor. But it fails when I run a job.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.xxx.com/dy_leanghy/leanghy-test.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab.xxx.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

Noted: I already allow iptable rule for my gitlab-runner can access to my gitlab server via port 443.

```
root@gitlabrunner:~/.ssh# nc -vz gitlab.xxx.com 443
Connection to gitlab.xxx.com 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed by restart the docker. Because iptables chain had been dropped on my GitLab runner server. So I need to restart the docker service when I run:

```
systemctl restart netfilter-persistent
```